# Plugin doesn't work with appended elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, append, wysiwyg, summernote

I use **bootstrap-summernote** for `div` element to create WYSIWYG editor.
All works fine, but when i append in DOM new div element with same class for `bootstrap-summernote`, they don't work with them. 
I read that for new-appended elements i must use something about that (event `on`)

```
 $(document).on('click', 'p', function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
```

So i've wrote:

```
 $(document).on('load', '.summernote', function(){
        $('.summernote').summernote({
            height: 300,
            lang: 'ru-RU'
        });
    });
```

And it still doesn't work.
But this example with `p` element works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xV3HN/1/

Comment: I don't think there's such thing as a `load` event for a `div`.

Comment: I thought it's something like `on document load`, not on `div` 
But click event, also not suitable in that case :/

Comment: You can re-attach the plugin to the new elements you've created exactly after creating them. You might have some place in the code where these new `divs` are been added to the DOM.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/xV3HN/6/

Comment: I'm gonna post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, I believe the best way to achieve that is to attach the `summernote` widget to the dynamically created elements at the point they're created.

Something around these lines:

```
$(function () {
    $("#add").on('click', function () {
        // A new div is being created.
        var div = $('<div>').appendTo($("#container"));

        // Attach the summernote widget to it.
        div.summernote();
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/xV3HN/6/)